# Stata: Using egen, anycount() when values vary for each observation

Tags: stata

Each observation in my data presents a player who follows some random pattern. Variables `move1` up represent on which moves each player was active. I need to count the number of times each player was active:

The data look as follows (with `_count` representing a variable that I would like to generate). The number of moves can also be different depending on simulation.

```
+------------+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| simulation | playerlist | move1 | move2 | move3 | move4 | move5 | move6 | _count |
+------------+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|          1 |          1 |     1 |     1 |     1 |     2 | .     | .     |      3 |
|          1 |          2 |     2 |     2 |     4 |     4 | .     | .     |      2 |
|          2 |          3 |     1 |     2 |     3 |     3 | 3     | 3     |      4 |
|          2 |          4 |     4 |     1 |     2 |     3 | 3     | 3     |      1 |
+------------+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
```

`egen` combined with `anycount()` is not applicable in this case because the argument for the `value()` option is not a constant integer.

I have made an attempt to cycle through each observation and use `egen` rowwise (see below) but it keeps `count` as missing (as initialised) and is not very efficient (I have 50,000 observations). Is there a way to do this in Stata?

```
gen _count =.  
quietly forval i = 1/`=_N' {  
    egen temp = anycount(move*), values( `=`playerlist'[`i']')
    replace _count = temp
    drop temp
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily cut out the loop over observations. In addition, `egen` is only to be used for convenience, never speed.

```
gen _count = 0 
quietly forval j = 1/6 {  
    replace _count = _count + (move`j' == playerlist)
}
```

or

```
gen _count = move1 == playerlist 
quietly forval j = 2/6 {  
    replace _count = _count + (move`j' == playerlist)
}
```

Even if you had been determined to use `egen`, the loop need only be over the distinct values of `playerlist`, not all the observations. Say the maximum is 42

```
gen _count = 0 
quietly forval k = 1/42 { 
    egen temp = anycount(move*), value(`k') 
    replace _count = _count + temp  
    drop temp 
}
```

But that's still a lousy method for your problem. (I wrote the original of `anycount()` so I can say why it was written.)

See also http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0046 for a review of working rowwise.

P.S. Your code contains bugs.

You `replace` your count variable in **all** observations by the last value calculated for the count in the **last** observation.

Values are compared with a local macro `playerlist`. You presumably have no local macro of that name, so the macro is evaluated as empty. The result is that you end by comparing each value of your `move*` variables with the observation numbers. You meant to use the variable name `playerlist`, but the single quotation marks force the macro interpretation.

For the record, this fixes both bugs:

```
  gen _count = .  
  quietly forval i = 1/`=_N' {  
      egen temp = anycount(move*), values(`= playerlist[`i']')
      replace _count = temp in `i' 
      drop temp
  }
```